# What is the purpose of @Update's OnConflictStrategy in Room?

Tags: android-room

I understand why setting an `OnConflictStrategy` for an `@Insert` annotation makes sense -- if the client is inserting a record that already exists, the database configuration needs to know how to reconcile that situation.

But I don't understand what it means to set an `OnConflictStrategy` on an `@Update` annotation. Isn't the idea of `@Update` to necessarily expect a row in the database that already exists, and then update it? Is that considered a "conflict"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is rather about constraints, not about records that already exists.
For example, let's imagine table A which has foreign key that connects this table records with records from another table B.
If we will update foreign key value in table A with the value which does not exist in table B then we will violate constraint because in such case there are will be records in table A which does not relate to any records from table B.